# I can't run the gmapping node

Tags: slam, navigation, catkin, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm programming in c++ and I use catkin. I wanted to work with amcl node. But since it's not catkinised yet, I had to use the gmapping node. I followed the tutorial from here:

> http:// wiki.ros.org/ catkin/ Tutorials/ using_rosbuild_with_catkin

to get this node. I did each step. Now I want to run the node with the command

> $ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping
> scan:=base_scan

but it doesn't work, see the error message :

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable
> named slam_gmapping below
> /home/pauline/ros_ws/gmapping/gmapping

(I found the command to run it in here http:// wiki.ros.org/ gmapping)

I don't understand because I did

> $ rosmake gmapping

and it was successfull. Am I missing something here ??

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93726/i-can%27t-run-the-gmapping-node/) by [moutinoir](https://answers.ros.org/users/8066/moutinoir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which version of ROS are you running? I don't know if I understood well the question, but in Hydro there is the catkin version of both amcl and gmapping.

Where did you downloaded the package gmapping which you are trying to build with rosbuild?

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moutinoir](https://answers.ros.org/users/8066/moutinoir/) on 2013-10-26**:
thank you for your help, it worked by doing 'sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-slam-gmapping' instead of following the tutorial. (see the answer below for more details) :)